# One line for loop with object modification

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array of objects where each object has a `search_order` attribute.
I was to go over the array and increase that attribute by 1 for all objects
This is the easy way:

```
res = []
for r in array:
    r.search_order+=1
    res.append(r)
return iter(res)
```

Is there a one line `for` loop that can accomplish this?

```
return (r.search_order+=1 for r in array)
```

Doest seem to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be one line but this does the job correctly

```
def incr_search_order(x):
    x.search_order += 1
    return x

retrun map(incr_search_order, array)
<or>
return [incr_search_order(x) for x in array]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an assignment within generator expression or list comprehension (it will raise `SyntaxError`).

Instead add the attribute with 1 and reassign the result :

```
old_array=(r.search_order+1 for r in array)
```